# integer array element with leading 0 showing garbage output

Tags: c++

i have this small piece of code that has an integer array containing some elements with a leading 0.

```
int arr[]={012,234,071};
cout<<arr[0]<<endl; //output 10
cout<<arr[1]<<endl; //output 234
cout<<arr[2]<<endl; //output 57
```

for some reason am i getting different output for values with leading zeros,can someone explain this to me why is this happening?

Answer (score 4):

Numeric literals with leading zeros are assumed to be octal numbers. Don't use leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

> *integer array element with leading 0 showing garbage output*

You do not get "**garbage**" values; the compiler mainly interprets the values in your array that have leading zeros, like *012*, as octal values. The compiler then converts it into a decimal value (for *012*, it is *10*) and outputs that.

Don't use leading zeroes if you are working with the decimal system.

Comment: " values in your array that have trailing zeros as octal values." - That would be leading zeros.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Sorry for the vocab confusion. I'll fix it, give me a sec :)

Comment: @NeilButterworth I've adjusted my answer, could you please remove your above comment? Thanks!